# Python - Read file names in directory, write twice to text file (one without file extensions), and separate with pipe

Tags: python

I have a directory (c:\temp) with some files:

```
a.txt  
b.py  
c.html
```

I need to read all of the files in a directory and output it to a text file. I've got that part handled (I think):

```
WD = "c:\\temp"

import glob

files = glob.glob('*.*')
with open('dirList.txt', 'w') as in_files:
    for eachfile in files: in_files.write(eachfile + '\n')
```

I need the output to look like:

```
a|a.txt  
b|b.py  
c|c.html
```

I'm not quite sure where to look next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd split the file name by `.` and take the first part:

```
for eachfile in files:
    in_files.write('%s|%s\n' % (eachfile.split('.')[0], eachfile))
```

Comment: Brilliant! That worked like a charm. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You have almost solved your problem. I am not quite sure where you are getting stuck. If all you need to write is the file name (without extension) followed by `|` then you just need to update your code as this:

```
import glob

files = glob.glob('*.*')
with open('dirList.txt', 'w') as in_files:
    for eachfile in files:
        file_name_without_extension = eachfile.split(".")[0]
        in_files.write( file_name_without_extension + "|" + eachfile 
+ '\n')
```

Comment: Thank you, V. Singh! That worked too. After seeing the solution, I definitely should have figured that one out.